# Java Swing Thread Library

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am currently looking for a Thread Management Library for Swing(like Foxtrot). As Foxtrot is not supported in Java 7, any suggestions on any other library that are supported in Java 7 ?

Comment: What specific features are you using from Foxtrot? Since Java 1.5, there is the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) standard package, and since 1.6 there is the [`javax.swing.SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class which helps in thread management.

Comment: *"As Foxtrot is not supported in Java 7"*  What does that mean?  Java APIs should be forward compatible.

Comment: @AndrewThompson While (generally) true, he probably refers to the [project's site](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/docs/), where it says `It is compatible with the J2SE, and has been tested with version 1.3.x, 1.4.x, 5.0.x. and 6.0.x`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas.  To be clear, 'untested' does not mean the same thing as 'unsupported'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give [SPIN](http://spin.sourceforge.net/solution.html) a try. It also has EDT-Rerouting facility and I have tested it against JDK 7U10 - works.